# Where is the ROS distributions folder in Debian?

Tags: ros-melodic, debian

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I'm new in ROS, I'm trying to use the qtcreator plugin but I no know where is the ROS distibutions folder, I just installed ROS from the [official doc for Debian](http://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation/Debian#Debian_install_of_ROS_Melodic). An interesting details is that looking at the Packages content:

`wget -qO- http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/buster/main/binary-amd64/Packages | grep Package`

I have the following output:

```
Package: python-bloom
Package: python-catkin-pkg
Package: python-catkin-pkg-modules
Package: python-catkin-tools
Package: python-osrf-pycommon
Package: python-rosdep
Package: python-rosdistro
Package: python-rosdistro-modules
Package: python-rosinstall
Package: python-rosinstall-generator
Package: python-rospkg
Package: python-rospkg-modules
Package: python-vcstool
Package: python-vcstools
Package: python-wstool
Package: python3-bloom
Package: python3-catkin-pkg
Package: python3-catkin-pkg-modules
Package: python3-catkin-tools
Package: python3-colcon-argcomplete
Package: python3-colcon-bash
Package: python3-colcon-bazel
Package: python3-colcon-cmake
Package: python3-colcon-common-extensions
Package: python3-colcon-core
Package: python3-colcon-defaults
Package: python3-colcon-devtools
Package: python3-colcon-library-path
Package: python3-colcon-metadata
Package: python3-colcon-mixin
Package: python3-colcon-notification
Package: python3-colcon-output
Package: python3-colcon-package-information
Package: python3-colcon-package-selection
Package: python3-colcon-parallel-executor
Package: python3-colcon-pkg-config
Package: python3-colcon-powershell
Package: python3-colcon-python-setup-py
Package: python3-colcon-recursive-crawl
Package: python3-colcon-ros
Package: python3-colcon-test-result
Package: python3-colcon-zsh
Package: python3-osrf-pycommon
Package: python3-px4sitl
Package: python3-rocker
Package: python3-rosdep
Package: python3-rosdistro
Package: python3-rosdistro-modules
Package: python3-rosinstall
Package: python3-rosinstall-generator
Package: python3-rospkg
Package: python3-rospkg-modules
Package: python3-vcstool
Package: python3-vcstools
Package: python3-wstool
```

Maybe this means that most ROS packages was installed from the main Debian repository, I'm trying to use `dpkg -L` to figure out the relevant folder but I can't, any hint please.
There is any link to install melodic from source or with a standalone installer?
Than you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/332189/where-is-the-ros-distributions-folder-in-debian?/) by [denisacostaq](https://answers.ros.org/users/45337/denisacostaq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-09-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you look at the point  1.6 in the instruction, you see where the stuff is:

You see it uses the path /opt/ros/molodic/

If you like to have you own build see here

http://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation/Source

---

Originally posted by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) with karma: 1999 on 2019-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [denisacostaq](https://answers.ros.org/users/45337/denisacostaq/) on 2019-09-02**:
Sorry, `/opt/ros` does not exist in my host, look at this command output for example:
`dpkg -L ros-map-msgs`

/.

/usr

/usr/share

/usr/share/doc

/usr/share/doc/ros-map-msgs

/usr/share/doc/ros-map-msgs/changelog.Debian.gz

/usr/share/doc/ros-map-msgs/copyright

/usr/share/map_msgs

/usr/share/map_msgs/msg

/usr/share/map_msgs/msg/OccupancyGridUpdate.msg

/usr/share/map_msgs/msg/PointCloud2Update.msg

/usr/share/map_msgs/msg/ProjectedMap.msg

/usr/share/map_msgs/msg/ProjectedMapInfo.msg

/usr/share/map_msgs/srv

/usr/share/map_msgs/srv/GetMapROI.srv

/usr/share/map_msgs/srv/GetPointMap.srv

/usr/share/map_msgs/srv/GetPointMapROI.srv

/usr/share/map_msgs/srv/ProjectedMapsInfo.srv

/usr/share/map_msgs/srv/SaveMap.srv

/usr/share/map_msgs/srv/SetMapProjections.srv

**Comment by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) on 2019-09-03**:
Could you add the output of" apt search ros-melodic "

**Comment by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) on 2019-09-03**:
You bigger problem is that you have buster. If you look at http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/stretch/main/binary-amd64/Packages

You see the comment ros pkgs arm missing.

You may try this link
https://wiki.debian.org/DebianScience/Robotics/ROS/OnBuster

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-09-03**:
I believe the OP is running into [wiki/UpstreamPackages](http://wiki.ros.org/UpstreamPackages).